# PostGIS ST_Buffer with attribute preserve

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I'm playing with PostGIS a little bit but I'm stuck on, I think simple thing - how to create buffer from points with attribute inheritence?
Simple st_buffer code:

```
CREATE TABLE buffer AS
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom,1) AS geom
FROM ne_110m_populated_places;
```

Original point layer (ne_110m_populated_places) have 100 columns, result has only geom column.
I'm trying to put rest of attribute table from source to target layer but I'm stuck.
I can easly select columns with st_intersect:

```
SELECT ne_110m_populated_places.*, buffer.*
FROM ne_110m_populated_places 
INNER JOIN buffer ON ST_Intersects(ne_110m_populated_places.geom,buffer.geom);
```

But can't connect both to do the task.

Comment: Why don't you select also id into the buffer table?

Comment: You don't even need to create `buffer` if you just use `ST_DWithin` on the query. This then becomes a self-join. Alternatively, you could just add the columns you want to preserve to the buffer creation.

Comment: I can add columns manually to buffer creation but I have around 100 columns, and will be quite hard to add it one by one.

Comment: If you don't want to use `*` nor to manually type all the fields, then just have Postgres generate the field list: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get this right, just add all columns to the new table and drop the old `geom` column:

```
CREATE TABLE buffer AS
  SELECT *,
         ST_Buffer(geom, 1)::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, <SRID>) AS _geom
  FROM   ne_110m_populated_places
;

ALTER TABLE buffer
  DROP COLUMN geom
;

ALTER TABLE buffer
  RENAME _geom TO geom
;

CREATE INDEX ON buffer USING GIST(geom);
```

You can (almost) freely choose (and manipulate) the columns to copy in the `SELECT` list, just as with your second query!?

Or, if you don't intend to keep the original geometries, update the table with

```
ALTER TABLE ne_110m_populated_places
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(POLYGON, <SRID>)
    USING ST_Buffer(geom, 1)
;
```

Note that nothing keeps you from adding a second geometry column. It's not best practice, though.

---

Alternatively, the relational way; create a table with the buffers and the original `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE buffers AS
   SELECT <pkey_col>,
          ST_Buffer(geom, 1)::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) AS geom
   FROM   ne_110m_populated_places
;

ALTER TABLE buffer
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (<pkey_col>)
;

ALTER TABLE buffer
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (<pkey_col>)
    REFERENCING ne_110m_populated_places (<pkey_col>)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
;

CREATE INDEX ON buffer USING GIST(geom);
```

You can now `JOIN` both tables `USING <pkey_col>` and choose all wanted columns from `ne_110m_populated_places`, plus the `geom` from `buffer`.

---

Run `VACUUM ANALYZE buffer;` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but this is just a simple SQL issue - you can select multiple columns from the places table...

You're trying:

```
CREATE TABLE buffer AS
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom,1) AS geom
FROM ne_110m_populated_places;
```

But you can also select everything from the places table - adding an alias to the table illustrates this best:

```
SELECT
p.place_name
, p.place_id
, p.whatever
, p.geom
, ST_Buffer(p.geom,1) AS geom_buff
FROM ne_110m_populated_places as p;
```

As stated, there may be ways to avoid using the buffer using ST_DWithin, unless you want to keep that buffer geometry - the STDwithin cuts out the middle man aka. the geom_buff and does the work internally, which is great if you need it.